# Link error in a C++/CLI application linking a static C++/CLI library

Tags: c++-cli, static-libraries

I have a static C++/CLI library in which the following class is defined:

**ObjectWrapper.h:**

```cpp
public ref class CObjectWrapper: System::Object
{
public:
    CObjectWrapper(CObject& wrappedObject);

    explicit operator CObject*();

private:
    CObject& m_WrappedObject;
};
```

**ObjectWrapper.cpp:**

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BasicObjectWrapper.h"

CObjectWrapper::CObjectWrapper(CObject& wrappedObject)
  : WrappedObject(wrappedObject)
{ }

CObjectWrapper::operator CObject*()
{
    return &WrappedObject;
}
```

I have a C++/CLI application which is linked to the static library. The following errors arise at link:

> Error  3   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000007) `CObjectWrapper::.ctor`  KCBrowserInEcrinView.obj
>
> Error  4   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000005) `CObjectWrapper::.ctor`  KCBrowserLibD9.lib
>
> Error  5   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000008) `CObjectWrapper::op_Implicit`    KCBrowserInEcrinView.obj
>
> Error  6   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000006) `CObjectWrapper::op_Implicit`    KCBrowserLibD9.lib

I solved the problem by moving the implementation (previously located in the .cpp file) to the .h file. I don't understand why.

I would highly appreciate if anybody could bring any explication.

Comment: Static link libraries with managed code are not supported by the linker.  The equivalent is an assembly.  A DLL, linking happens at runtime.

Comment: @Hans Thanks for your answer. I must be missing something since the linking with the static library works, with the trick that I described at the end of my message.

Comment: You are, the code comes from the header file, not the library.  Same thing as putting all of your source code files in one project.

Comment: Another question. I have another class in the same library `ref class CObjectFactory: someNamespace::IObjectFactory` which defines `virtual Object^ Create()`. The implementation is in the .cpp file. Contrary to the CObjectWrapper object, there is no link problem with this method. What is the reason ?